# Create a subclass object with initialized parent object

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a BaseEntity class, which defines a bunch (a lot) of non-required properties and has most of functionality. I extend this class in two others, which have some extra methods, as well as initialize one required property.

```
class BaseEntity(object):

    def __init__(self, request_url):
        self.clearAllFilters()
        super(BaseEntity, self).__init__(request_url=request_url)

    @property
    def filter1(self):
        return self.filter1

    @filter1.setter
    def filter1(self, some_value):
        self.filter1 = some_value
    ...
    def clearAllFilters(self):
        self.filter1 = None
        self.filter2 = None
        ...

    def someCommonAction1(self):
        ...

class DefinedEntity1(BaseEntity):

    def __init__(self):
        super(BaseEntity, self).__init__(request_url="someUrl1")

    def foo():
        ...

class DefinedEntity2(BaseEntity):

    def __init__(self):
         super(ConsensusSequenceApi, self).__init__(request_url="someUrl2")

    def bar(self):
        ...
```

What I would like is to initialize a BaseEntity object once, with all the filters specified, and then use it to create each of the DefinedEntities, i.e.

```
baseObject = BaseEntity(None)
baseObject.filter1 = "boo"
baseObject.filter2 = "moo"

entity1 = baseObject.create(DefinedEntity1)
```

Looking for pythonic ideas, since I've just switched from statically typed language and still trying to grasp the power of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
import copy

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, sth, blah):
        self.sth = sth
        self.blah = blah

    def do_sth(self):
        print(self.sth, self.blah)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

    def do_sth(self):
        print(self.param, self.sth, self.blah)

a = A("one", "two")
almost_b = copy.deepcopy(a)
almost_b.__class__ = B
B.__init__(almost_b, "three")
almost_b.do_sth() # it would print "three one two"
```

Keep in mind that Python is an extremely open language with lot of dynamic modification possibilities and it is better not to abuse them. From clean code point of view I would use just a plain old call to superconstructor.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Radoslaw. It does feel like a hack, though... Could you elaborate on "plain old call to superconstructor"? Keep in mind, though, that I would like to avoid the situation where I need to supply all the properties each time I create a subclass object.

Comment: Why not just have an optional parameter on the constructor for class B that takes a class A and sets the class B properties to the class A values?

Comment: Well, Python has no supernatural abilities allowing it to know which fields added to the base class you want to use in the subclass entities (by the way - there is no need for a property getter and setter to be implemented if it does nothing additional - as in case of your). You can make a subclass constructor that takes superclass instance, checks its fields dictionary (using vars - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) and then decide to add some of them (based on value type, attribute name or parsed annotation) to itself.

Comment: Still, it is against the basic OOP principles. It is known as creating object from prototype. Python does not support the prototyping paradigmate. It could be emulated by clever use of the powerful introspection features, but will always feel a bit hacky. As Steve Cohen mentioned - in 99% of cases it would be better to use conventional methods (create a subclass contructor that takes properties values from superclass instance).

Comment: I was thinking of passing the superclass object to subclass constructor before, but it felt weird, since the superclass is just there.... But reading through your comments and thinking more about it, I also don't see any better way. Thanks for great insights, guys. They will help me make my code more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP and was able to use the idea from Radosław Łazarz above of explicitly setting the **class** attribute of the object to the subclass, but without the deep copy:

```
class A:
    def __init__(a) : pass
    def amethod(a) : return 'aresult'

class B(A):
    def __init__(b) : pass
    def bmethod(self) : return 'bresult'

a=A()
print(f"{a} of class {a.__class__} is {''  if isinstance(a,B) else ' not'} an instance of B")

a.__class__=B # here is where the magic happens!
print(f"{a} of class {a.__class__} is {''  if isinstance(a,B) else ' not'} an instance of B")
print(f"a.amethod()={a.amethod()} a.bmethod()={a.bmethod()}")
```

Output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x00000169F74DBE88> of class <class '__main__.A'> is  not an instance of B
<__main__.B object at 0x00000169F74DBE88> of class <class '__main__.B'> is  an instance of B
a.amethod()=aresult a.bmethod()=bresult
```